# How to remove unused/ (already uninstalled) sql db engine services from ssms history in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Connect to Server

```
Server type: Database Engine
Server name: MANITEJ
           MANITEJ\SQLFOR_23
           MANITEJ
           MANITEJ\TCSHYD 
           MANITEJ\MANI 
           MANITEJ\MANI MANITEJ\SERVER_1 
           <Browse for more...>

Authentication:

User name:
Password:

            Connect   Cancel   Help   Options >>
```

How to remove history in SSMS tool which we get at the time of connect to server/object explorer for uninstalled SQL Server 2019 instances.

From above description we can find 'MANITEJ' server instances many. Now I want to remove those from SSMS tool since those instances are uninstalled.

Comment: Just hover with your mouse over the entry you want to remove so that is highlighted (like your `MANITEJ\SQLFOR_23`)  and hit the `Delete` key on your keyboard .

Comment: It is just deleting name, but the instance remains in history when I'm opening ssms again all those instances are visible.

Comment: You must not click on that entry to select it. Just hover over it, so that the dropdown stays open! Works for me. Just removed one instance, reopened SSMS and it stays gone ...